# Highcharts: How to extend the x axis beyond the last column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column chart with a couple of columns.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yishaib/emX5T/

The design calls for the x-axis to extend to the right, far beyond the last column.
Any ideas how I would do that?

This is what I'm aiming for:

[image]

coffee script:

```
$("#container").highcharts
chart:
  spacingRight: 200
  type : 'column'
  width: 305
  height: 250  

series: [data: [71, 29]]

xAxis:
  categories: ['Column A','Column B']      
  tickWidth: 0

yAxis:
  min: 0
  title:
    text: ''
  labels:
    enabled: false
  gridLineWidth: 0
```

Comment: add some null values in data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
You need to specify more requirements for the chart if you do not want to keep the default items. This still lets you extend the xAxis beyond the 2 data points. To adjust the width of the points you need to use a mixture of one or more of the following: [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval), [`pointWidth`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointWidth), [`pointInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointInterval), and perhaps some others.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/d7esv/) is an updated jsFiddle with some modifications to your code in regular js.

You would have to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/tCXu8/). Note that the label formatter does not work (I am not familiar with coffee script) but the basic idea is there. You first need to set how many categories you want to show with `max: xxxx`. This will extend the xAxis out. You then probably want to hide that "5" so you need to use the label formatter function.

```
xAxis:
  categories: ['Column A','Column B']      
  tickWidth: 0
  max: 5
  labels:
    formatter: function() {
                if (this.value <> 5) {
                    return this.value;
        }
            }
```

Comment: It works! I tried using the max setting but wasn't familiar with the label formatter. Nice!

Comment: Not a problem. Coffee script looks interesting.

Comment: Answer un-accepted since I discovered that this causes the columns to be become closer together. Each column width becomes smaller and their labels overlap.

Comment: You would need to modify the col width and spacing to accommodate your desired output. Also remove the `spacingRight`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing a similar thing with a Highcharts line chart, but the concept applies to column graphs as well (I suspect other types too though I have not explicitly tried).  The solution relies on creating a "hidden series" in your chart that is as long as the number of categories you have on the X axis.

First, you will want to set the [chart.ignoreHiddenSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) option of the chart to true in the Highcharts option object.  Then, when you create the series, set the [visible](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.visible) option of the series to false (alternatively you can call [hide()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide%28%29) on the series when you create it) and set the [showInLegend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.showInLegend) option the of the series to false as well.

Here is a jsFiddle which shows the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8PpDN/1/.  This fiddle was branched off the example for [chart.ignoreHiddenSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) provided in the [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

For quick reference, here is the fiddle's javascript code. Notice that there are as many 0s in the hidden series data array as there are categories on the xAxis.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [
            {data: [100, 60]}, 
            {data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], visibility:'hidden', showInLegend:false}
        ]
    });
});
```

Now, does not exactly match the requirement as there are category labels under the x axis, which do not appear in the screen shot.  In that case, just provide empty strings for category labels, and eliminate the ticks altogether (set [minorTickLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minorTickLength) and [tickLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickLength) in the xAxis options to 0) to achieve the same effect.

Here is jsfiddle showing that: http://jsfiddle.net/BMncj/1/ and again the javascript code from the fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
            type: 'column'
        },
        legend: {enabled:false},
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Series 1', 'Series 2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
            minorTickLength:0,
            tickLength:0
        },
        series: [
            {data: [100, 60]}, 
            {data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], visibility:'hidden', showInLegend:false}
        ]
    });
});
```

From here you can play with the length of the x axis extension by adjusting the number of categories, and/or adjusting the interval options available as previously referenced.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's an interesting approach. 
Since posting this question, I've actually decided to implement my chart using pure HTML and CSS. The chart was simple enough and ditching highcharts simplified things and gave me a lot of freedom in styling and design that was just too cumbersome using highcharts.
For instance, I see your solution causes the columns to be off-center, a bit to the left. This is probably due to space left for the the hidden column.

Comment: @yishaib Yes you are right about the off centered-ness.  I hadn't noticed it until you just pointed it out.  I'm sure there is a way to address it, but sounds like you are much happier with your solution.  Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to use it with line charts, and I simply replace 'column' with 'line' in your example code which does not work. Could you share your code with line charts? Thanks